# String concat in roslyn CSharpScripting

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, string-concatenation

I am building a script engine using Roslyn Scripting in .Net 3 .I used [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples) wiki to learn few basics in Scripting API and trying to create a simple string concat. The following is the line i tried:-

```
 using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
 using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting; //imports

 Console.WriteLine(await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("a+b").ConfigureAwait(false));
```

The Expected output was ab.But Current Output is blank but if i try integers the result is proper.Can you please explain how script evaulates string data type.

Comment: Thanks i was dumb one step further if i want to explicity convert int to string the return value  then how we can do it for example the same code ````Console.WriteLine(await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("2+2").ConfigureAwait(false));```` i want to return 4 as string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `EvaluateAsync` you have to write C# code, and strings in C# are always in quotes.

`Console.WriteLine(await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("\"a\"+\"b\"").ConfigureAwait(false));`

Without them you are concatenating / adding the variables a and b.